# How do I obtain an Azure Flute in Generation IV?

Tags: cheats, pokemon-fourth-generation

I would like to catch an Arceus, but I don't know how to use the cheat to obtain an Azure Flute without an *Action Replay*, which is too risky. How can I catch the Original One without the high risk of my DSI crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Flute was never distributed. The only ways to obtain an Arceus in a gen IV game were through the following events:

- **2010 (Europe)**

  Through a movie giveaway from 17th February 2010 to 28th May 2010.
- **2009 (America & Japan)**

  At Toys 'R' Us from 7th November 2009 to 15th November 2009.

  And in Japan from 5th November 2009 to 16th November 2009 through a movie giveaway.

Otherwise, you could also obtain it in Gen V games, Black/White through the Pokemon Global Link following a vote from all people across the world. It was available in Japan from 5th November 2010 to 31st January 2011 and 1st February 2012 to 1st May 2012 for USA, Europe and other countries, that's when I got my Arceus.

You can get more details [here](http://serebii.net/events/dex/493.shtml).

Comment: I do not have Wi-Fi on my DSI, so I cannot use that method. The Arceus event is also over, so I cannot use that method either.

Comment: @Anonymous Well, yea, what I was also trying to say is that you cannot get Arceus now. :(

Comment: Please notify me if this question needs to be on a new page... Have the US Nintendo events ever had repeats on Pokemon, such as a Mewtwo giveaway on two different events? If so, there may be another Arceus giveaway.

Comment: @Anonymous It's okay. For Mewtwo, no, there's been only one event, since, after all, Mewtwo is available on quite a lot of games; Red/Blue/Yellow, FireRed/LeafGreen, HeartGold/SoulSilver, and now X/Y. However, you can see that [Mew](http://serebii.net/events/dex/151.shtml) has been given numerous times. You can browse the site I linked for more events. There are dropdowns near the top of there, where you can select the Pokemon you want to see. There might be another Arceus giveaway, but only the future will tell.